# Libgdx Batch without ApplicationListener

Tags: java, libgdx, desktop-application, bluej

Hi i'm looking for a way to display a Libgdx sprite batch, or something like this, without using any Application Listener, Adapter or the Game class.It should be possible to call a constructor of some gameobject and then it's texture should be displayed to a batch or some window.

The reason is, that i want to use a desktop-application-project in class with students to start programming lessons and therefore we use BlueJ. But features like the object inspector aren't working, if there's an active application thread and things like Gdx.files ends in a nullpointer exception.
In later lessons there will be an application but in the beginning that goes too far.

All my attempts with the Game class or self written ApplicationListeners weren't succesfull. I hope somebody out there has a idea.

Comment: Not sure what the limitation is, that you can't use the Game class. And are you teaching LibGDX specifically, or what?

Comment: No i'm teaching java and i'm analysing different "graphics" frameworks like swing javafx and libgdx and compare their benefits to know wich of them is the easiest and best to use for people who like to create projects for teaching in class without the students caring much about the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

A SpriteBacth draws to a Screen. Application Listener/Adapter and Game is needed to manage the screens. The SpriteBach assumes you have a Screen, a LibGDX Screen, not just any Screen, and does not magically know what you want it to draw on. 
You cannot just instantiate an object from one library and expect it to magically work in a different library.

I fail to see the point of it even if it were to work. Either use LibGDX or don't.

You would be much better off using something like JavaFX. It is built into java and is easy to draw images and sprites to a window. You can use JavaFX to make games AND desktop applications.

Comment: Well i'm comparing JavaFX, Swing and Libgdx to their use to create easy gameprojects for students so that they don't have to care much about the GUI. I got several criteria they have to deal with and one of those is the use in BlueJ. So the objects the learners would create, carry sth like a texture and with a static call these textures are displayed to a screen, without them programming how. In Swing for example it works easy with a frame implemented as singleton and objects carriing an bufferedImage are adding theirselves into a list on the frame and call paint(). Im looking for this in gdx

Comment: I would avoid Swing. But in JavaFX and libgdx its very simple to load a texture and display it. Just don't mix the two libraries together.

Comment: The projects realized in this comparison are very easy an have no need to be performant or well developped its just about making your very first steps in programming and achieving big results with very very little code. Its about motivating students who have no interests in programming and every result u get is on the console.So i'm searching an easy way to create a window in libgdx. And I'm not mixing the three things i'm implementing three implementations seperatly

Comment: libgdx gives you a window right out of the box. It even loads a texture for you and display it. All you need to do is run the project. With very little effort you can create a base project for students to add objects to and make a simple game.

Comment: Yeah you are right if u run a project it's very simple. That's why I wanted to work with it. The problem is i want or have to use the IDE BlueJ and to use BlueJ's benefits i can't just run an applicationListener or adapter or game. Or what do u mean with run a project?

Comment: I mean open the project, build it and run it. I have never used BlueJ but I assume you can build a project or at least run it in a debug mode. ApplicationListener/Adapter and Game are just classes that you extend.